# Passing an http query string with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, url, switch-statement, jquery-load

I am trying to load a div with .load(). I have tried:

```
function newPage(p_id){
    var id = p_id;
    $("#div").load("content.php?id=id");

}
```

Now php does not receive the value of id, but the string "id" is receiving the value. Then I tried:

```
function newPage(p_id){
    var id = p_id;

    switch(id){
        case 1:
            $("#div").load("content.php?id=1");
            break;
        case 2:
            $("#div").load("content.php?id=1");
            break;
        default:
            alert("Default");
            break;
    }
}
```

In this case the default is executed even if the value of id is 1 or 2.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this -

```
$("#div").load("content.php?id="+id);
```